# blogger | why is my javascript code only shows one post?

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

so i tried to make my own javaScript function that shows my recent posts in my blogger homepage .. everything was alright until i figured out that it only shows one post not all .. is there a line of code missing ?

here is the code:

```js
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    function homePageRecentPost (root) {
        var entries = root.feed.entry || [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            var posts = entries[i];
            var postTitle = posts.title.$t;
            var originalThumbnailUrl = posts.media$thumbnail ? posts.media$thumbnail.url : 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWtp_qRPNT8/UZYmQq5sAdI/AAAAAAAAEec/7YDbpK4Q6g8/s72-c/default+image.png';
            var newThumbnailUrl = originalThumbnailUrl.replace('/s72-c','');
            var links = posts.link || [];
            for ( var j = 0; j < links.length; ++j) {
                if (links[j].rel == 'alternate') break;
            }
            
        }
        var postUrl = links[j].href;
        var imgTag = '<a href="' + links + '">' +'<img src="' + newThumbnailUrl+ '" alt="' + postTitle + '">' + '</a>';
        document.write(imgTag);
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

and that's the call Back:

```js
<script src='/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=8&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=homePageRecentPost'/>
```

Comment: Why you write the document only once? Not in the loop?

Comment: Your script code is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check these lines:

```
var postUrl = links[j].href;
var imgTag = '<a href="' + links + '">' +'<img src="' + newThumbnailUrl+ '" alt="' + postTitle + '">' + '</a>';
document.write(imgTag);
```

Maybe you want this inside the loop like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
    var posts = entries[i];
    var postTitle = posts.title.$t;
    var originalThumbnailUrl = posts.media$thumbnail ? posts.media$thumbnail.url : 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWtp_qRPNT8/UZYmQq5sAdI/AAAAAAAAEec/7YDbpK4Q6g8/s72-c/default+image.png';
    var newThumbnailUrl = originalThumbnailUrl.replace('/s72-c','');
    var links = posts.link || [];
    for ( var j = 0; j < links.length; ++j) {
        if (links[j].rel == 'alternate') break;
    }

    var postUrl = links[j].href;
    var imgTag = '<a href="' + links + '">' +'<img src="' + newThumbnailUrl+ '" alt="' + postTitle + '">' + '</a>';
    document.write(imgTag);
}
```

And I suggest you to use `let` if you don't need global variable.

Comment: i figured it out :D .. all i had to do was to add <div> into a var and then i used push() method to make the imgTag inside it ..

Answer (score 0):

the solution was i had to make a var and add 'div' inside it then i used push() method to make imgTag inside it ..

```js
 <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    function homePageRecentPost (root) {
        var entries = root.feed.entry || [];
        var html = ['<div>'];
        for ( var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            var posts = entries[i];
            var postTitle = posts.title.$t;
            var originalThumbnailUrl = posts.media$thumbnail ? posts.media$thumbnail.url : 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWtp_qRPNT8/UZYmQq5sAdI/AAAAAAAAEec/7YDbpK4Q6g8/s72-c/default+image.png';
            var newThumbnailUrl = originalThumbnailUrl.replace('/s72-c','');
            var links = posts.link || [];
            for ( var j = 0; j < links.length; ++j) {
                if (links[j].rel == 'alternate') break;
            }
            var postUrl = links[j].href;
            var imgTag = '<a href="' + links + '">' +'<img src="' + newThumbnailUrl+ '" alt="' + postTitle + '">' + '</a>';
            html.push('<div class="bs-item">', imgTag, '</div>');

        }
        
        html.push('</div>');
        document.write(html.join(""));
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Well it basically same like my answer, only you give another container